# Dynamically create ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, menuitem

In my application I want to dynamically build up a context-menu. The first `MenuItem` is static and the second one should be a `Separator`. All items after the `Separator` are dynamically created at runtime.

I don't want to use code-behind becaus I'm working with the MVVM-Pattern.
My idea now was to create an `interface` called `IAppMenuItem` with the following three implementations

- ModifyMenuItem (Static `MenuItem`)
- SeparatorMenuItem
- ExecuteMenuItem (Dynamic `MenuItem`

In the viewmodel of my application I've created an `ObservableCollection<IAppMenuItem>` which contains the `ContextMenu`-Items.

Until here everything works fine. My problem is the presentation of the `ContextMenu`-Items in the UI.

I tried to set the correct controls with the following `DataTemplate`s in the Resources of the view.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:SeparatorMenuItem}">
    <Separator/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ModifyMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Header="Edit items"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ExecuteMenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The definition of my `ContextMenu` is just:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsCollection}"/>
```

The `DataTemplate`s are working fine, but the controls are drawn inside a `MenuItem`. So for example for the `Separator` I see in the UI a `Separator`-Control inside a `MenuItem`-Control. But I need the `Separator` to be the Control.

Anyone have an idea how to set the Controls inside the `DataTemplate`s directly to the contextmenu?

---

**Update:**

The complete `ContextMenu` looks like:

```
<ToggleButton Margin="0,0,10,0"
              AutomationProperties.Name="Update"
              AutomationProperties.AutomationId="Update_List"
              Content="Update"
              AttachedProperties:ButtonExtensions.IsDropDownButton="True"
              Style="{StaticResource GenericToggleButtonStyle}">
    <ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
        <controls:CustomContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsCollection}">
            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ExecuteMenuItem}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ModifyMenuItem}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit items"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ContextMenu.Resources>
        </controls:CustomContextMenu>       
    </ToggleButton.ContextMenu>
</ToggleButton>
```

The GenericToggleButtonStyle is just:

```
<Style x:Key="GenericToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3,1" />
</Style>
```

Here is a screenshot of the `MenuItem`s

[image: MenuItems]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the incorrect `MenuItems` on the UI?

Comment: Please see updated answer to resolve "inner" `MenuItems`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you set the `ItemSource` property on a `ContextMenu` the default `ItemContainer` used is `MenuItem`. This is why the `Separator` is rendered as a `MenuItem`.

You can fix this by implementing your own `ContextMenu` control that inherits from `ContextMenu`.

You need to override the `IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride` and `GetContainerForItemOverride` methods.

Please see my example below:

```
public class CustomContextMenu 
    : ContextMenu
{
    private bool _mustGenerateAsSeparator = false;

    protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
    {
         _mustGenerateAsSeparator = (item is SeparatorMenuItem);

         return base.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(item);            
    }

    protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        if (_mustGenerateAsSeparator)
        {
            return new Separator { Style = this.FindResource(MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey) as System.Windows.Style };
        }
        else 
        {
            return base.GetContainerForItemOverride();                      
        }            
    }
}
```

`Style = this.FindResource(MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey) as System.Windows.Style` is needed as you have to apply the default `MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey` style to get the default separator style.

This link pointed me into the right direction http://drwpf.com/blog/category/item-containers/

How to use the custom control in XAML:

window declaration :`xmlns:cnt="your namespace"`

```
<Label Content="Dynamic Menu">
        <Label.ContextMenu>                
            <cnt:CustomContextMenu x:Name="contextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemsCollection}">                    
                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary>                            
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ExecuteMenuItem}">
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayText}"></MenuItem>
                        </DataTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ModifyMenuItem}">
                            <MenuItem Header="{Binding DisplayText}"></MenuItem>
                        </DataTemplate>                            
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ContextMenu.Resources>
            </model:CustomContextMenu>                            
        </Label.ContextMenu>
    </Label>
```

Second Part of the question:

Update your data templates to use `TextBlock` as they will be rendered inside a `MenuItem`, please see below:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ModifyMenuItem}">
    <TextBlock Header="Edit items"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ExecuteMenuItem}">
    <TextBlock Header="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Really cool. The separator works perfect. Still having the problem with the other items. There is a `MenuItem` drawn inside another `MenuItem`.

Comment: Can you post your entire XAML from your context menu? Or a screenshot of the incorrect menuitems?